# Gluing together ggplots to as closely as possible mimic the face_wrap()

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, plot, tidyverse

I was wondering if there might be a way to **glue together** `p1` and `p2` plots to ***as closely as possible*** get the appearance (e.g., a single `xlab` and `ylab`, `vs` value printed in a `gray strip`) of my `Desired_plot`?

```
library(ggplot2)
dat1 = subset(mtcars, vs == 0)
dat2 = subset(mtcars, vs == 1)

p1 <- ggplot(dat1, aes(mpg,vs)) + geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(dat2, aes(mpg,vs)) + geom_point()

Desired_plot <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,vs)) + geom_point() + 
                                           facet_wrap(~vs)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the strips you either need to fit geoms or annotations to the plots. I think an easier way would be to make them as individual ggplots and stick them on top using patchwork:

```r
library(patchwork)

p3 <- ggplot(mapping = aes(x = 1, y = 1)) + 
  theme_void() + 
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(color = NA, fill = 'gray85'),
        plot.margin = margin(6, 6, 0, 6))

p4 <- p3 + geom_text(aes(label = 1))
p3 <- p3 + geom_text(aes(label = 0))
p2 <- p2 + 
  theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = margin(0, 3, 6, 3))
p1 <- p1 +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(0, 6, 6, 6),
        axis.title.x = element_text(hjust = 1))

(p3 + p4) / (p1 + p2) + plot_layout(heights = c(1, 15))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This gets you pretty close. We could probably get right up to it if we take more margin padding out.

```
library(patchwork)
p1 + (p2 + scale_y_continuous(labels = NULL, name = NULL) + 
        theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
              plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1,0), "line")))
```

[image]